# Subversion: New Project requirements

Tags: svn, version-control, clearcase, branching-and-merging

I am new to Subversion. I am working in ClearCase from past few years. We got a new Project, where our Client needs his work to be done on Subversion, as it is a Open source SW. As a newbie and CM for our Project, I would like to know:

1. What are the requirements to initiate a Project and before going for repository creation
2. How do I make Branch structure same as ClearCase in Subversion?
3. What are the basic requirements to initiate a Project?
4. How tagging can be done?

These all I should mention in one of the Document. I need all your inputs. Please dont thing bad. My Queries are in perspective of technical and managerial Queries. I need to give inputs to my Manager. Any inputs from professional end? Your inputs are most valuable for our Project.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that this is not really a question which can be answered in Q/A format. I suggest reading [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/) to learn more about Apache Subversion and version-control in general.

- I don't understand the first question in the list,
- the answer to the second one can be found in [SVNBook | Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html),
- the third one is also unclear,
- the fourth one is also covered in [SVNBook | Tags](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.tags.html).

Read the manual and ask specific questions about those parts / chapters that are unclear to you.